# The use of "slam" in the context of poetry and poetry competitions 'dans la Francophonie'

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, poésie

There’s a very cool event happening right now in [my wife’s French  hometown](http://www.amblainville.fr/-festimots-festival-de-contes-slam-.html) and the [event’s brochure](http://www.amblainville.fr/IMG/pdf/festimots_2016_prog_v2w.pdf) mentions that there’s an “Atelier d’écriture **slam**” scheduled for 15H30, followed by  a “Grand tournoi 
de **slam**-poésie“ at 16H with participation encouraged by  the following : « Un **slam** dit, un cadeau offert ».

The use of “slam” as an adjective in “d’écriture slam” and even as part of the hyphenated noun “slam-poésie” are fairly consistent with my understanding of the use of [“slam”](http://www.powerpoetry.org/actions/5-tips-slam-poetry) in English to describe a poetry event/competition/tournament, but **“Un slam dit”** in the brochure’s above call for participation seems to be using “slam” as a noun by itself to mean the poem/poetry itself.

The French Wikipedia entry for [“slam (poésie)”](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slam_%28po%C3%A9sie%29) under the [**En France**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slam_%28po%C3%A9sie%29#En_France) heading, paragraph 4, does mention the existence of confusion with the term’s usage, but this seems to be referring to confusion about whether the mere public presentation of poetry (with no competition involved) qualifies as “un slam,” and not to the term’s use as a noun to refer to the poems themselves.

Further below under the cited entry’s [**“Règles habituelles du slam”**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slam_%28po%C3%A9sie%29#R.C3.A8gles_habituelles_du_slam) heading, the final “rule” includes language nearly identical to the language used in the “Festi Mot’s” brochure, to-wit:

“Un **texte** dit = un verre offert (est l'exception culturelle francophone)” …

… which tempts me to extrapolate that **slam** = **texte** as used in the brochure.

So my question is:

In the Francophone-wide world of “poetry slams” and “slam poetry,” is “slam” commonly used alone as a noun to refer to the poems/texts of poems presented and heard at “slam events/tournaments”  (as an abbreviation for “slam-poésie”?)?

or is it a regional (Picardie, France?) use?

or perhaps was its use this way in the brochure simply a result of a lack of space in the brochure?

Comment: Souvent rencontré employé comme nom. Exemples. [Projet d'écriture d'un slam](http://www.circ-ien-colmar-ash.ac-strasbourg.fr/spip.php?article258), écrire un slam à la manière de Grand Corps Malade. [un  slam, un jour](http://unslam.unjour.over-blog.com/). [« Monique clôture la scène par un slam d’hommage aux enfants. Je la rejoins sur scène pour un dernier slam.  »](http://www.icem-pedagogie-freinet.org/book/export/html/956). Et sur cette dernière page le mot employé dans des occurrences variées.

Comment: I thought there was a word play with maybe the event being held on Sat. i.e. _slam dit_ sounded like samedi but actually that item was on Sunday!

Comment: Like you, I was a priori (at least a bit) surprised by "un slam", so my first thought was: true, till now I don't know that "slam" could be a noun in French. But I finally realized that another, very current, use is: "du slam". So as a begin of answer: it's sure that "slam" can be a noun, at least as uncountable one. Then, since it's a relatively new word in French, why not admit that it's evolving to become countable too...?

Comment: @L'aditdabenlà Yes, they certainly missed a good marketing opportunity by holding it a day late: "Ce samedi: Un slam dit, un cadeau gratuit!" (ben oui, "cadeau gratuit" est redondant [mesdames], mais que voulez vous, il ne s'agit qu'un Slam!) Thanks!

Comment: @cFreed “Du Slam”! Yes, of course, the **genre** of such poems, just as [du] *Rap* (in both languages) is  the genre of (and short for) “[musique de] RAP [music]!” Prompting me to understand just that use as an uncountable noun was answer-worthy in itself, imo, & regardless, certainly worthy of these “Thanks” of mine!  Back to “Rap,” has that word evolved to countable status to refer to one “rap song”? If so, I think a quick discussion of that, comparing it to “my” word would be a slam dunk of an answer that I’d love to see you provide (and get “2 points” for)!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words! But I'll not post an answer, I wouldn't feel it as legitimate: beyond what I wrote yesterday, I now realized even more widely how "slam" is used as a noun. See the @Laure's comment, which already cited as soon as your OP was posted. I also lately remembered that we currently say not only "du slam" but  also "le slam" (yet another uncountable usage). Regarding "rap", it's the same: "du rap" (to qualify a piece of music), "le rap" (to designate a genre, as you said) are commonly used, and "un rap" tends to be used to outright designate a piece of music _as an object_.

Comment: @cFreed Thanks for the follow-up, and I totally understand, agree with, and find admirable your position on not bending to external pressure to turn comments into answers. Even when exerted with kind (and truthful, in this case) words, such pressure can nevertheless be stressful and out of place, and I apologize for that. With Laure 's multitude of great cited examples and your many great thoughts, I've got my answer!! Thanks again!

Comment: I feel compelled to repeat me: again, thanks for the kind words! And as we (StackExchange users) are not allowed to sustain long comments exchanges I planned to propose you don't answer to this one, but with a French expression I'd in mind... and couldn't translate! So it inspired me a question you might find of interest: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/89271/english-equivalent-for-french-assaut-de-courtoisie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When french are using an english word, they first use it like english would do, then they try to make it french. Generally by adding -er after the verb to make it a first group verb and make it easy for everyone.

For example with "stop" (un stop, stoppeur, stoppeuse, stopper) or "bluff" (un bluff, bluffeur, bluffeuse, bluffer). We can see that it feel natural for "slam" to be "[un slam](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/slam/10910198)", "[slameur", slameuse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/slameur/10910340)" and "[slamer](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/slamer/186761)". I think those are now accepted french words because the link I provided is "Larousse" a very famous french dictionnary.

Now, "slam" as an adjectif ("poésie slam") is not in the Larousse french dictionnary, rigth now. It seem to me that there would be very few use case for such an adjective ("texte slam", "rythme slam", "diction slam" ?). Moreother, I think that "poésie slam" is a [pleonasme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%A9onasme). If it's "un slam" it's already poetry, and you could simply use "slam" instead.

Comment: Thanks for the great links and analysis! I notice that the *Larousse* entry for “un slam” doesn’t include the original (and still primary) English meaning, which is the word for the actual competition/gathering (between/of the poets) itself, and not for the poetry performed/heard at such venues. I also find interesting the use of “déclamer” for the verb (which in English has some possible pejorative connotations), whereas in English, the more neutral, non-pejorative verbs [“perform” & “read,”](http://www.powerpoetry.org/actions/5-tips-slam-poetry) (and sometimes “recite”) are usually used.